# Почему не меняются данные в таблице? Команда UPDATE - php

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование, phpmyadmin

Почему **не меняются** данные в таблице? Команда **UPDATE** - php

**Код обработчик**:

```
$vidreds = $_POST['id'];//
$vstatus = 'novisible';

$link->set_charset('utf8');
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `singles` SET M=('$vstatus') WHERE id='$vidreds'");
```

**Код формы:**

```
<form action="editfilms.php" method="post">     
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="main__table-text" name="<?php echo $film["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $film["id"]; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="main__table-text"><?php echo $film["title"]; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="main__table-text main__table-text--rate"><i class="icon ion-ios-star"></i> <?php echo $film["rating"]; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="main__table-text"><?php echo $film["genre"]; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="main__table-text"><?php echo $film["views"]; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="main__table-text main__table-text--green"><?php echo $film["M"]; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="main__table-text"><?php echo $film["date"]; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                            </tr>
                            <button type="submit">YES YES YES</button>
                        </tbody> 
                    </form> <?php } ?>
```

В `echo $film["id"]` передаётся ID строки который передаётся в код обработчика. Только вот... столбец **"M"** не меняется на **novisible**

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$film["id"];?>">
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Глобальные  переменные всегда  получают value ну, а  к форме  обащаются по name.

```
<div class="main__table-text" name="<?php echo $film["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $film["id"]; ?></div>
```

вот  тут уберите name file_id

и  добавьте код коллеги выше . Это скрытое  поле  которое  будет  получать ваша глобальная переменная.